# How to speed up the training of an RNN model with multiple GPUs in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, multiple-gpu

For example, the RNN is a dynamic 3-layer bidirectional LSTM with the hidden vector size of 200 (`tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`) and I have 4 GPUs to train the model. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530023/data-parallelism-for-rnn-in-tensorflow) using `data parallelism` on subsets of samples in a batch but that didn't speed up the training process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try [model parallelism](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/model_parallel_lstm.html). One way to do this is to make a cell wrapper like this, which will create cells on a specific device:

```py
class DeviceCellWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
  def __init__(self, cell, device):
    self._cell = cell
    self._device = device

  @property
  def state_size(self):
    return self._cell.state_size

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return self._cell.output_size

  def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    with tf.device(self._device):
      return self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
```

Then place each individual layer onto dedicated GPU:

```py
cell_fw = DeviceCellWrapper(cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, state_is_tuple=False), device='/gpu:0')
cell_bw = DeviceCellWrapper(cell=tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, state_is_tuple=False), device='/gpu:0')
outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```